# Disable socket.io polling on change tab

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to disable the `polling` with socket.io client. When i change tab/window, socket.io will polling connection, but i don't want this. I've check on the options, but no result.

My socket.io config :

```
  const socket = useRef(
    io("http://localhost:3001", {
      autoConnect: false,
      transports: ["websocket"],
      upgrade: false,
    })
  );
```

Anyone know if i can disabled this feature ?

Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean "polling"?  From the client-side `transports: ["websocket"]` will force socket.io to only use the webSocket transport so it will not start out with http polling.  All webSocket connections, however, start with an HTTP request so perhaps that is what you are seeing.  There should be ONE http request that initiates each websocket connection and each time you reload a page that uses a webSocket connection in the browser, it will make a new webSocket connection.

Comment: Also, don't set `upgrade: false`.  That specifically tells socket.io NOT to upgrade to the websocket transport.  Remove that option entirely.